# gm: resize image if it is wider than 1000px

Tags: javascript, meteor, graphicsmagick, collectionfs

I am trying to do some image manipulation via `gm` in `collectionFS`, because I need to read a stream and write it back to the same file, I have to use a temp-file - like shown below.

I want to check if the image is wider than 1000px. In this case it should be re-sized to 1000px.

Unfortunately this doesn't work, as I got the errors `TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'pipe'` and `Error: gm().stream() or gm().write() with a non-readable stream.`

```
var fs       = Npm.require('fs'),
    file     = Images.findOne({ _id: fileId }),
    read     = file.createReadStream('public'),
    filename = '/tmp/gm_' + Date.now(),
    temp     = fs.createWriteStream(filename);

if (method == 'resize') {
    // resize to 1000px, if image is bigger
    gmread = gm(read);
    gmread.size(function(err, size){
        if(size.width > 1000) {
            gmread.resize('1000').stream();
        }
    });
}

gmread.on('end', Meteor.bindEnvironment(function (error, result) {
    if (error) console.warn(error);

    var tmpread = fs.createReadStream(filename);
        write   = file.createWriteStream('public');

    tmpread.on('end', Meteor.bindEnvironment(function (error, result) { 
        if (error) console.warn(error);
    }));

    tmpread.pipe(write);
}));

gmread.pipe(temp);
```

Comment: Are you using cfs:graphicsmagick?

Comment: Does `gm.isAvailable()` return true? If not, then there are no binaries on the system for gm to actually work.

Comment: Yes, gm is working well, as I can do a simple crop or something like that. But I'm not very familiar with gm, so I don't know how to do that resize, as it leads to a nested function... If I do just `resize('1000')` it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the correct way in collectionFS is something like this:

```
var gmread = gm(readStream, fileObj.name());
gmread.size({bufferStream: true}, FS.Utility.safeCallback(function (error, size) {
    if (error) console.warn(error);
    else {
        if(size.width > 1000) gmread.resize('1000').stream().pipe(writeStream);
    }
}));
```

Mybe you want to put that into a `transformWrite`-function for your store...

Answer (score 0):

You can let GraphicsMagick do the test. Try

```
gmread.resize('1000x50000>');
```

instead of

```
gmread.size(function(err, size){
    if(size.width > 1000) {
        gmread.resize('1000').stream();
    }
```

See the GraphicsMagick ["geometry"](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/GraphicsMagick.html#details-geometry) page.